# Do NTP servers log ip addresses

Tags: ntp

There are many NTP servers like time.google.com time.cloudfare.com and so on . Do these services log ip addresses of the visitors?Have heard that http servers do log ip addresses and though not related to this qestion , removal of ip address is required by GDPR.

Answer (score 5):

It's not common for NTP servers to keep log data of requests from clients, although they can.

Computers configured to synchronize with certain NTP server aren't considered *visitors* as with web sites, because the setup is typically more permanent.

IP addresses aren't (necessarily) PII per GDPR, unless they are used as *Online identifiers for profiling and identification* ([Recital 30](https://gdpr.eu/recital-30-online-identifiers-for-profiling-and-identification/)). That would be highly unlikely with NTP, as there wouldn't even be point in profiling NTP users.

Answer (score -1):

Network Time wouldn't have personal data, so it would be a moot point. Here's the wiki page for you to read.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation

Comment: The Wikipedia article of GDPR is an awfully wide and unofficial source compared to narrow perspective in the question. Therefore, it's not that useful as a reference here.

Comment: An IP address in conjunction of a timestamp is a personal data. In many cases even the ip alone address is a personal data.

Comment: An IP and a timestamp is not personally identifiable information in regards to NTP! Unless it can be correlated to a name and address.  I didn't want to include the regs themselves since they are quite heavy reading. But I'll try and find some others to improve the answer.